# Text Formatting issue with bootstrap

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, styling, pgp

Question, I'm trying to enable 2FA via pgp on my site and I'm having an issue with bootstrap smushing the pgp encrypted message. It's not a huge deal but it requires users to manually unsmush the text when putting it into their pgp software. When I inspect the DOM I see that it appears to retain it's proper format like this

[dev tools inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06SIN.png)

but it appears like this

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQYF0.png)

Any ideas?

Here is my code

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
<?php if(isset($encrypted_secret)): ?>
  <div class="panel panel-info" style="width: 140%;">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-title">Key Challenge</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="panel-body">
    <form name="verify_key" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('users/settings/'.$userdata['username']); ?>" role="form">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">                   
           <?= $encrypted_secret; ?><br><br>
           <b> Use your private key to decrypt this message </b>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="verify_key" class="form-control" placeholder="enter decrypted message">
            </div>
        </div>   
      </div>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group pull-left">
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" value="Submit"></input> 
         </div>
       </div>
       </div>
     </form>
   </div>
 </div>
<?php else: ?>
```

Comment: this may be just a language barrier... but what do you mean exactly by smushing/unsmushing?

Comment: If you want something rendered exactly as the "source" string, you probably want to embed that text in a pre tag.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is the line breaks, `nl2br()` would do the trick by adding a `<br>` tag on each newline.

If, more unlikely, your issue is that the code inspector shows a "fixed width" output while yours doesn't, you'd need to enclose the text in `<pre>` tags or use a fixed-width font such as courier so that each line looks the same as long as it has the same amount of characters (like the PGP message does)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and in regards to your above comment, what I mean by smush/unsmush is that the user will copy the text as it's rendered with improper line breaks into their pgp software and it won't decrypt. It's really just a convenience thing, thanks again for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Use [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to add the proper line breaks.

```
<?= nl2br($encrypted_secret); ?>
```